# url.pathname sending the pathname followed by https,www

Tags: javascript, url

I have a URL object that is made from a link. When I generate the object like so

```js
var post = new URL("https://www.reddit.com/r/BetterDiscord/comments/vz6xq7/i_forgot_the_name_of_this_plugin");
```

The pathname is /r/BetterDiscord/comments/vz6xq7/i_forgot_the_name_of_this_plugin,https,www.

and here's the thing. It's only THIS URL (at least as far as I can tell, when generating a different URL (take https://www.reddit.com/r/BetterDiscord/comments/yuoqv/better_discord_plugins/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

it works just fine

(that being the pathname is r/BetterDiscord/comments/yuoqv/better_discord_plugins/)

I have tried bodging it like so

```js
Logger.info(url.pathname.split(",")[0])
```

I don't understand why either of them aren't working.

Comment: I just tried to log using ```console.log(post.pathname.split(",")[0])```. it worked exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really strange but it just started working using the .split method but oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯